# Add a list in parent list on basis of parameter

Tags: c#

There are 2 classes :

```
public class RiseData{
public int AccountId{get;set;}
public List<CashData> CashList{get;set;} //and other params
}

public class CashData{
public int AccountId{get;set;}  //and other params
}
```

I am getting some data in form as below:

```
List<RiseData> distinctRiseData = riseDataList.FindAll(x => x.RecordType == "P").ToList();
                   
List<Cash> cashListDirty = cashList.FindAll(x => x.RecordType == "C").ToList();
```

I am trying to fill the cashListDirty to distinctRiseData on the basis of where distinctRiseData.Record.AccountId=cashListDirty.Record.AccountId

Lets say there are 10 records in cashListDirty where 2 records have same AccountId as 1 record in  distinctRiseData . I should add those 2 records in distinctRiseData record with the same AccountId.
Tried this but doesn't works:

```
foreach(var i in distinctRiseData )
                    {
                        var data = cashListDirty .FindAll(x => x.AccountId == i.AccountId).ToList();
                        i.CashList.Add(data);
                    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: adding list you should use AddRange() no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use linq Join to get the required result

```
var cashList = distinctRiseData.Join(cashListDirty, d => d.Record.AccountId, c => c.Record.AccountId, (d, c) => new {d, c}).Select(c => c.c);
```

Read about linq join at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins)

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what is happening in the code above . Can you please elaborate just a bit please . Thanks

Comment: The above method takes two collection and Join those based on expression defined as 2nd and 3rd parameter. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins

Comment: thanks. i was also trying with above method and it worked for 
i.CashList= data; still i will definitely try linq tomorrow morning. once again thank you